# C# LINQ unable to enumerate matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I  declared a 3 X 3 Matrix

```
int[,] matrix=new int[3,3]
                {
                   {1,2,3},
                   {4,5,6},
                   {11,34,56}
                };
```

when i try to enumerate it  like

```
var diagonal = matrix.AsQueryable().Select();
```

I am unbale to convert it as enumerable collection.How to do that?

Answer (score 9):

Rectangular arrays don't implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` type, so you'll need a call to `Cast<>`. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[,] matrix=new int[3,3]
                {
                   {1,2,3},
                   {4,5,6},
                   {11,34,56}
                };

        IEnumerable<int> values = matrix.Cast<int>()
                                        .Select(x => x * x);
        foreach (int x in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
121
1156
3136
```

Answer (score 1):

`AsQueryable()` is meaningless when applied to array. `Select` doesn't have overloads without parameters.

`matrix` (multidimensional array) is `IEnumerable` itself. If you want to query it, you need to cast it to `IEnumerable<int>` using `matrix.Cast<int>()`, it will produce sequence of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11 ...

If you want to get diagonal in Linqish way you should do:

```
var diagonal = Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0)).Select(i => matrix[i, i]);
```